# Why doesn't camera_calibration.cpp tutorial code read from my camera correctly?

Tags: opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I am getting the following error when trying to run camera_calibration.cpp in the calib3d module of OpenCV's tutorial code samples, in streaming mode: `Input does not exist: Invalid input detected. Application stopping.` The input line in the xml input file looks like this: `<Input>0</Input>`, which should get the "0th" camera on my system.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by enclosing the camera index in double quotes: `<Input>0</Input>` became `<Input>"0"</Input>`.  (Simplistic parser... oh well, hope this helps some people.)